# AWS API gateway Custom Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to implement custom authorizer lambda function via java SDK. Can somebody tell me the exact format of the JSON response that is expected from my lambda function. Also in which format i should return the output (JSON object or policy object).

```
{
    "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:1234567:myapiId/staging/POST/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
      }
    ]
    },
    "principalId": "User123"
}
```

this is the format i am providing in output in `JSONObject` format but getting error

> Mon Apr 10 09:42:35 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after
>   transformations:
>   {"type":"TOKEN","authorizationToken":"ABC123","methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-1:007183653813:ohlqxu9p57/null/GET/"}
>   Mon Apr 10 09:42:36 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration
>   error: Authorizer function failed with response body:
>   {"errorMessage":"An error occurred during JSON serialization of
>   response","errorType":"java.lang.RuntimeException","stackTrace":[],"cause":{"errorMessage":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   JsonObject (through reference chain:
>   com.google.gson.JsonObject[\"asString\"])","errorType":"java.io.UncheckedIOException","stackTrace":[],"cause":{"errorMessage":"JsonObject
>   (through reference chain:
>   com.google.gson.JsonObject[\"asString\"])","errorType":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException","stackTrace":["com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:199)","com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:683)","com.f
>   [TRUNCATED] Mon Apr 10 09:42:36 UTC 2017 :
>   AuthorizerConfigurationException

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is Lambda framework related.

Essentially, Lambda will invoke the handler function and pass a serialized JSON.

```
public class LambdaCustomAuthorizer implements RequestHandler<AuthorizationRequestDO, Object> {


public Object handleRequest(AuthorizationRequestDO input, Context context) { }
```

}

When you work with custom authorizer, API gateway passes following JSON to your lambda function:

{
    "type":"TOKEN",
    "authorizationToken":"",
    "methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:::///"
}

you should have a custom DO AuthorizationRequestDO

which is a POJO::

public class AuthorizationRequestDO {

```
 String authorizationToken;
 String methodArn;      


public String getAuthorizationToken() {
    return authorizationToken;
}
public void setAuthorizationToken(String authorizationToken) {
    this.authorizationToken = authorizationToken;
}
public String getMethodArn() {
    return methodArn;
}
public void setMethodArn(String methodArn) {
    this.methodArn = methodArn;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AuthorizationRequestDO [authorizationToken=" + authorizationToken + ", methodArn=" + methodArn
            + ", getAuthorizationToken()=" + getAuthorizationToken() + ", getMethodArn()=" + getMethodArn() + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: The problem was with what to return as a output of the custom authorizer lambda function.I was returning a JSON string IAM policy which was throwing serialization error.What i did was created a POJO class equivalent of IAM policy and return the object of this POJO class as output which solved the isssue. Again this is a bug in AWS lambda.It can only serialize POJO classes and not primitive datatypes and wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Resource` property should be a single `string` value.

```
{
    "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:1234567:myapiId/staging/POST/*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
      }
    ]
    },
    "principalId": "User123"
}
```

Comment: Its single string only....anyways the issue is gone now.Turned out to be a thing with AWS lambda.